# Translating shortcut keys

Tags: windows, internationalization, keyboard-shortcuts

When extracting strings from a desktop Windows application for translation, should I translate shortcut keys as well?

In other words, should Ctrl-C copy to the clipboard even for Chinese software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CTRL-C is universal. You can safely assume that typical CTRL-something shortcuts behave the same in all (modern) Windows versions, regardless of the language.
However, there might be several ways to present them depending on the language. For example, French would translate the name of the key (the combination remains the same).

But you are asking about Chinese (presumably Simplified Chinese), which will simply display it as CTRL-C. After all, the keyboard layout is the same (with the same symbols), all they do differently is they use so-called Input Method Editors. And although there are several different IMEs, I haven't yet seen the one that would override CTRL-C...